# Any tips on compiling PyQt for Centos 5.5?

Tags: pyqt

I have installed a bunch of qt packages - qt, qt-devel, qt4, qt4-devel, sip but can't get latest PyQt4 to compile.

I've pointed the configure script at my qt4lib as such

```
python configure.py -q /usr/lib64/qt4/bin/qmake --verbose
```

but getting errors like

```
DBus v1 does not seem to be installed.
cfgtest_QtHelp.cpp:1:25: error: qhelpengine.h: No such file or directory
sip: /mnt/hgfs/rnp_repos/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.8.1/sip/QtCore/qabstractitemmodel.sip:156: syntax error
Error: Unable to create the C++ code.
```

EDIT: Found out that SIP v4.11.2 is required for PyQt 4.8 but still can't make without errors. At least python configure.py finishes now.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Grab the PyQt4 SRPM from Fedora and rebuild using mock. You may need to look a few versions back for one that will compile against the version of Qt 4 in CentOS.

Comment: Any suggestions on where to learn about mock? Extremely unGoogleable message here.

(dev)[root@seed rnp_repos]# mock -r centos-4-x86_64 rebuild install PyQt4-4.8.1-1.fc15.x86_64.rpm


You need to be a member of the mock group for this to work

Comment: You need to be a member of the `mock` group. Use `usermod -a -G` to add yourself to the group and then relog.

Answer (score 0):

I've just successfully compiled PyQt 4.8 on Centos 5.5. I went down the route of building Qt4 from source - using qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.1.tar.gz from Nokia.

Had to obtain various *-devel packages before Qt's ./configure would complete - see http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/requirements-x11.html (don't worry about the version numbers being slightly lower than required).

Also I used Python 2.6 from the EPEL 5 repository (python26-devel). Just remember when building PyQt to run python26 configure.py (and not the default Python). I don't know if this will improve your mileage in building PyQt but we're porting an application from Windows which was already using 2.6 so this route was necessary for me.

Not going to post my entire .bash_history here (much trial and error!) but if you're trying this and get stuck please ask a question.